# What are these white spots on my Basil Leaves?

Tags: herbs, basil

My basil plant has some odd white spots on the lower leaves. The upper leaves look like healthy leaves, with only the lower ones being affected. Some pictures of a sample leaf: [image: Top side of the leaves] [image: Bottom side of the leaves] Any ideas as to what they could be and how to treat them?

Extra info: I live in South Florida and recently had to add sand to the top of the soil to keep snails from munching on the leaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That grazed look on the leaves says thrips damage to me. Not sure that all the black specks in the second picture are soil, some may be black thrips. Spraying with neem should help, but make sure you spray beneath the leaves as well as the tops and stems http://homeguides.sfgate.com/can-spray-plants-keep-bugs-away-basil-leaves-90744.html

Comment: Can you usually see distinguishable features (antenna, legs, etc) on black thrips with the naked eye or do they just look like specks?

Comment: Like specks... you could use a magnifying glass!